# Flex Regular Expression Conversion Help

Tags: python, regex, apache-flex

I'm having a problem converting a regular expression from Python into Flex. My string is something like this:

```
SELECT "col", othercol,\n "othercol3" FROM doesn'tmatter...
```

Python matches just fine:

```
>>> re.search('select(.*?)from', 'SELECT "col", othercol,\n "othercol3" FROM doesn\'tmatter...', re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE).groups()[0]

' "col", othercol,\n "othercol3" '
```

But when I try it in Flex:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /select(.*?)from/ig;
var match:Array = pattern.exec('SELECT "col", othercol,\n "othercol3" FROM doesn\'tmatter...');
trace(match);
```

`match` always ends up null. What am I doing wrong? I'm sure it's obvious to a seasoned Flex programmer...

Comment: Maybe this implementation is non-greedy by default and you have to omit the `?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the many Flex regular expression testers out there:

http://www.idsklijnsma.nl/regexps/

For one thing, you're using dotall, etc., so you might want to know that Flex use the "s" flag for that. And the "x" flag ignores whitespace, etc. For example,

`pattern:RegExp = /select.+?from/gis;`

works for me on your example.

Comment: Thanks, the dotall flag is what I needed.